# phpmailer установка типа вложения

Tags: php, phpmailer

Использую phpmailer для отправки сообщения на почту, с одной картинкой.
Но вот беда, на почте когда приходит вложение - отображает его тип как 
**application/octet-stream**

Я уже вручную пробовал установить

```
$mail->AddAttachment($path, 'Файл', 'base64', 'image/jpeg');
```

И все равно тип приходит **application/octet-stream**

Comment: Можете погонять дебагер. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L2560. Вы смотрели тело емэйла? Какие `Content-Type` там указаны?

Comment: Устанавливаю метод $mail->isHTML(true);